# Using gdata with channel or user

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata, youtube-channels

I am trying to use the YouTube API v2.0 to retrieve videos from a user account.

i was able to receive videos from this account

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/REMAXIntl/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&

but when i try to use this account:

http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8dWY6fFXoqcMWPIqdN8JyA

I don't receive any videos. I think this may have to do with the url being different MEANING one points to users and one point to channels. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right different to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no videos in the channel with id "UC8dWY6fFXoqcMWPIqdN8JyA". There's a playlist, but it doesn't contain videos from that channel.

In general, you can just substitute in channel ids wherever you used to use a legacy username when constructing a GData API v2 URL. This is explained in more detail in this guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids